# I'm beginner and do not how to plot the Basins of attraction by the methods

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fractals, iteration

For a complex polynomial $P(z)$, define $T$ by
$T(z)=z-\frac{P(z)}{P^{\prime}(z)}$, where $P^{\prime}(z)$ is the first derivative of $P(z)$. We consider Newton method for finding the roots of polynomial $P(z)$, which is
given by the recursive formula

```
z_{n+1}=T(z_{n}), \ n\in\mathbb{N},\ \ \ \ (16)
```

where $T$ is defined as above. Similarly, we set a new method (and called it S iteration) where $T$ is defined as above, by

```
y_{n}=(1-\beta_{n})z_{n}+\beta_{n}Tz_{n}
z_{n+1}=(1-\alpha_{n})Tz_{n}+\alpha_{n}Ty_{n}, n\in\mathbb{N}, (17)
```

Now If the sequence $\{z_n\}_n\in\mathbb{N}$ (the orbit of the point $z_1$) converges
to a root $z^{\ast}$ of the polynomial $P$, then we say that $z_1$
is attracted by $z^{\ast}$. The attraction basin of the root $z^{\ast}$ of the
polynomial $P$ is the set of all starting points $z_1$ which are
attracted by $z^{\ast}$. If the  test polynomial is

```
P(z) = z^5 + z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z,  (18)
```

For this test polynomials $P(z)$ above, we consider
square domain is  centered at the origin in the complex
plane as follows

```
D=[-10,10]\times[-10,10].
```

If $\alpha_n=\beta_{n}= 0.8$ for all $n \in\mathbb{N}$ in S iteration method (17), To generate the basins of attraction and to study the
dynamics of methods (16) and (17), we divide the
domains $D$ into 250 × 250 grids. If the sequence
$\{z_n\}_n\in\mathbb{N}$ attempts a root of polynomial $P$ with accuracy of
$10^−4$ in number of iterations $n \leq 13$, then the converging
point $z_0$ is colored in a color assigned to $n$; otherwise, the
point is colored in white. Figure 1a, b (see the image in attach or in the link for clear picture https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00500-020-05038-9) represents the obtained basins of attraction by
Newton method (16) and S-iteration method (17) for the polynomial
$P$ defined in (18).

Now the attached pictures are generated by matlab and I want to generate the same pictures in mathematica.

[image]

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: `JuliaSetPlot[z - #/D[#, z] &[z^5 + z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z], z]`?

Answer (score 6):

For Newton's method, this could look as follows:

```
p = z^5 + z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z
znew = Together[z - p/D[p, z]]

cf = With[{
    p = p,
    num = N@HornerForm[Numerator[znew]],
    denom = N@HornerForm[Denominator[znew]]
    },
   Compile[{{z0, _Complex}, {maxiter, _Integer}, {\[Epsilon], _Real}},
    Block[{iter, z},
     z = z0;
     iter = 0;
     While[Abs[z] > \[Epsilon] && iter < maxiter,
      iter++;
      z = num/denom
      ];
     iter
     ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True
    ]
   ];

n = 1000;
gridpts = Tuples[Subdivide[-10., 10., n - 1], 2] . {1., 1. I};
result = cf[gridpts, 13, 1. 10^-4];

ArrayPlot[Partition[N[result], n],
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: How to write the code for S iteration (17)?

Comment: Well, I did mean to get you started, not to solve the problem for you...